# Production server using an outdated release of capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I deploy new version via capistrano to a Ubuntu 14.04 server and now Unicorn + Nginx setup is referring to inexistent release. I get the `ActionView::MissingTemplate` and also a `I18n::InvalidLocaleData` because it failed to load the `devise.en.yml` file.

I pretty much followed [this repo](https://github.com/m-gagne/ror-azure-demo). I already restart nginx and unicorn but still gives me the same error. It's searching on a `release/release_timestamp` that no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

You can at least confirm that Nginx is not part of the problem by directly connecting to the port or socket that Unicorn is listening on from within the server.

If Unicorn is running on a socket, see [Can Curl send requests to sockets?](https://superuser.com/questions/834307/can-curl-send-requests-to-sockets).